# Question about derivatives of complex-valued functions

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, complex-numbers

For $ z \in \mathbb{C}, t \in \mathbb{R}, \\f : \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}, \\a : \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \\b : \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

And given that $\frac{\partial f(z,t)}{\partial t} = a(z,t) +ib(z,t)$,
under what conditions will the following equations be true?

$\frac{\partial f^R(z,t)}{\partial t} = a(z,t) \\
\frac{\partial f^I(z,t)}{\partial t} = b(z,t)
$

where 
 $f^R : \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f^I : \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(z,t) = f^R(z,t)+if^I(z,t)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under any condition. Derivation is linear, so if $f=f^R+i\,f^I$ then
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial f^R}{\partial t}+i\,\frac{\partial f^I}{\partial t}.
$$
The real and imaginary parts of a complex number are unique, so you get your equality.

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic, but that should read 'any condition' (otherwise it would mean that the statement is false, and confusion follows).

Comment: Godd point.$\ $

Comment: @ChristianClason Couldn't it happen that $\frac{\partial f^R}{\partial t}$ or $\frac{\partial f^I}{\partial t}$ are functions with complex range(rather than real)? If so, then equations which i wrote may not hold.

Comment: No, because the real part and the imaginary part have real range by definition.

Comment: @ChristianClason I see, I was a bit unsure whether function with real range can have derivative with complex range, but I followed the definition of the derivative now, and it seems that you are right, since derivative of a function with real range is just a limit of difference between two real numbers, and it can not be complex.

Comment: Note that you were asking about the derivative with respect to $t$; a complex function $g(z)$ with real range (like the real or imaginary part of a complex function) cannot be differentiable with respect to $z$.